# Change styling when div is scrollable

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

Since scrollbars are often invisible, I would like to have a visual indicator when a div is scrollable (this is for certain things on mobile that would overflow the screen horizontally)

I'm not sure how to achieve this using CSS, *however* I remember seeing this in an article a couple years ago, so I think it's possible, potentially doing what might be described as a 'hack' or using a pretty obscure property.

```
<style>
.scroll-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.scroll-y::overflowing-y { /* not real */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 90%, rgba(120,120,120,.4));
}
</style>
<div class="scroll-y"></div>
```

Comment: you could probably do something for webkit using `-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo elements, but I don't believe there's a CSS only solution for detecting overflowed content.  Would most likely require a Javascript solution to cover all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is explicitly and deliberately made impossible in CSS:

https://wiki.csswg.org/faq#selectors-that-depend-on-layout

because styles applied based on scrollable status of the `<div>` could affect layout in a way that makes the `<div>` large enough not to be scrollable, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.. although I swear I saw a sort of hacky way of showing a gradient at the edge of scrollable content using a weird combination of selectors.. probably an :after so it wouldn't affect the styling of the main element

Comment: You can put a gradient overlaid near bottom edge of an element. The only limitation is that with pure CSS the gradient will be always there, whether the element overflows or not. It may not be immediately noticeable if you make it e.g. white on white.

Answer (score 0):

Kornel is correct that this is not possible using CSS in general, but it can be 'faked' under certain situations.

[This post by Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/) 
explains a method using two backgrounds, one which scrolls with the content, and one which doesn't, so when overlaid it appears to be the same background. The 'illusion' only works if the background color is solid, though.

Here is the code from Lea's article:

```
.scrollbox {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: 50px auto;

    background:
        /* Shadow covers */
        linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,

        /* Shadows */
        radial-gradient(50% 0, farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(50% 100%,farthest-side, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background:
        /* Shadow covers */
        linear-gradient(white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), white 70%) 0 100%,

        /* Shadows */
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 0, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)),
        radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% 100%, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,0)) 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 40px, 100% 40px, 100% 14px, 100% 14px;

    /* Opera doesn't support this in the shorthand */
    background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll;
}
```

There is also [this Codepen which also contains links to a few related resources](https://codepen.io/laustdeleuran/pen/DBaAu).